# How do I delete a message if I have the message.id in dyscord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Say I have a message id, how would I go about to delete that specific message by it's id in another channel?

I currently have a bot send user messages to another discord server with both the original and the bot message id's. Now when a user deletes their message from the original server, I want the bot to delete that message in my other server by message id.

My array with both message id's looks like this:

```
allmessages = [[id1,id2],[id1,id2],[id1,id2]] #. . . so on
```

I am using this to see when the user deletes a message:

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
```

In there I have a for loop that iterates through my messages to see which Id got deleted, and then I take the other Id which I want to delete. The part which deletes the message by it's Id... I have tried everything:

```
if message.channel.id == idGoesHere:
   channel = client.get_channel(theOtherChannelID)
   msg = IDIwantToDelete
   await msg.delete()
```

Or:

`await client.http.delete_message(channel, msg)`

Nothing works.

How do I delete a message by it's id in a channel, simple and easy?

I also don't want to hear answers which tell me to delete inside using the `on_message` listener function, that's not my use for the bot. I don't want to instantly delete a message, only when the delete listener gets called. Thank you.

Comment: Might have a solution. I think instead of the Id, I will store the message object. I think that should work when I delete the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the message object instead of the ID worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message) to retrieve the message object, then call its delete method:

```
msg = await channel.fetch_message(id)
await msg.delete()
```